# How can I change IIS application pool property setProfileEnvironment from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, azure-powershell

How can I set the "setProfileEnvironment" property from Powershell?

The following code is generating error *"The property 'setProfileEnvironment' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."*

```
$IISServerManager = Get-IISServerManager
$pool = $IISServerManager.ApplicationPools.Add("MyPoolName")
...
$pool.ProcessModel.LoadUserProfile = $true
$pool.ProcessModel.SetProfileEnvironment = $true
```

Comment: What's the operating system version?

Comment: What if you execute this script `Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/applicationPools/applicationPoolDefaults/processModel" -name "setProfileEnvironment" -value "True"
` alone? If it cannot work, too, what's the windows system and IIS version?

Comment: @LexLi Windows Server 2016 or Windows Server 2019.

Comment: @BruceZhang thanks, that worked.  If you change your response to an answer I will mark it accepted.  I am also adding an alternative I found, thanks to your response leading me in the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BruceZhang's answer worked, as does this:

```
Set-ItemProperty ("IIS:\AppPools\MyAppPoolName") -Name processModel.setProfileEnvironment -value "true"
```

Just make sure, if you are using the code block from the original post, that you commit the changes so the new application pool exists before calling the above command, using:

```
$IISServerManager.CommitChanges()
```